# QComboBox adjust drop down width

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qcombobox

Not sure why I cant get it to work, so maybe one of you will be able to see my mistake... :

```
combo_type = QComboBox()
combo_type.setMaximumWidth(50)
combo_type.addItems(["TEsst1111","TEsst11111111111111","TEsst1111111111111111111111111"])
combo_type.setStyleSheet('''*
    QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item
    {
    min-width: 6000px;
    }
''')
```

The idea is so that widget in UI has 50 width but when drop down and open I can read the list, sadly the stylesheet override don't change the drop down width making it 50 and unreadable...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorted... it was naming error. Correct answer posted below.

```
combo_type.setStyleSheet('''*    
QComboBox QAbstractItemView 
    {
    min-width: 150px;
    }
''')
```

Answer (score 3):

QComboBox already has a QListView inside it. See bellow:

```
combo_type = QComboBox()
view = combo_type.view()
view.setFixedWidth(200)
```

Just adjust *"200"* to your own value.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`QListView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#gridSize-prop):

```
combo_type = QComboBox()
combo_type.SizeAdjustPolicy(QComboBox.AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow)

view =  QListView() # creat a ListView
view.setFixedWidth(200) # set the ListView with fixed Width
combo_type.setView(view) # provide the list view to Combobox object

combo_type.setMaximumWidth(500) # will be overwritten by style-sheet
            combo_type.addItems(["TEsst1111","TEsst11111111111111","TEsst1111111111111111111111111"])
combo_type.setStyleSheet('''
QComboBox { max-width: 50px; min-height: 40px;}
QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item { min-height: 150px;}
QListView::item:selected { color: red; background-color: lightgray; min-width: 1000px;}"
''')
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for info but I have posted answer to my own question above/below... there was error it should have been QComboBox QAbstractItemView  instead of QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item. Still thanks for your example, I'm sure it will get handy one day !

Comment: @Dariusz , do you mean `QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item { min-height: 150px;}` cannot set height of the drop down list to be 150px while after you changed it to `QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item { min-height: 150px;}`? The previous style works on my side and no error show.

Comment: @Dariusz , actually the second and third is just to change the height only. If you want to just change the width. You don't need them.